# What is the advantage of force unwrapping an optional?

Tags: swift, performance, null, option-type, type-safety

If a variable is an `Optional` what is the advantage of force unwrapping it.

```
class Button: UIButton {
    var title: UILabel? = nil
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func addTitle(text: String) {
        title = UILabel(frame: CGRect())
        self.addSubview(title!)
    }

}

let a: Button = Button(frame: CGRect())
a.addTitle("Hello World")

// Case 1
a.title?.text = "Goodbye"

// Case 2
a.title!.text = "Hello World"
```

### Question

In ***Case 1*** I know its safer but is there any performance improvements or reason to use ***Case 2***?

So, if we know that ***Case 1*** is more safe why should we ever use ***Case 2***?

Comment: Your first case is not valid Swift code, it doesn't compile. `?` is used in optional chaining or in optional subscripting, so it should be followed by method call, property lookup or subscript.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear and so it compiles.

Comment: It's nice to use force unwrap when you know for certain there will always be data. It saves you from being forced to wire up an if-let or guard when it isn't necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance-wise there might be a very to very very small no difference between forced and optional binding/chaining, as the optional version might have an extra `if` somewhere.

But nonetheless when talking about performance issues, the performance bottlenecks come from other parts of the code, like non-improved loops,  lots of accumulation `NSNotification`'s sent in a short amount of time, unnecessary redraws of the UI, etc.

So it's best to stay on the safer side and use optional binding/casting/chaining and focus on the parts of the code that adds actual performance penalties. Even if at the time you write the code the value is guaranteed to be `non-nil`, in the future in might be that the conditions will change and you'll suddenly end up with crashes that you didn't expect they'll occur.

Swift has made it very easy to deal with optionals, without writing a lot of boilerplate code, you should take advantage of those features.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment, your example isn't actually valid. Putting that aside: force unwrapping means "I work only with a concrete value; I want to fail immediately if I don't have one". So it's often preferable to proceeding through that section of code with a `nil` value and then having some other problem sometime later once the causal nexus has been substantially eroded.

So: it allows you to be explicit about who owns responsibility for guaranteeing that a value is present.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Good (or at least defensible) reasons to use implicitly unwrapped `Optional`s, or to force unwrap an `Optional` using `!`:

- `@IBOutlet`s: These are normally implicitly unwrapped for a couple of reasons. You don't want to have to manually unwrap them every time you access them. But more importantly, if your outlets aren't hooked up right, you want to know immediately.
- Other instances where you make a conscious decision that you want the app to crash if a value is `nil`. For example, if you are instantiating a view controller from a storyboard and it is required to be a particular subclass of `UIViewController` called `MyViewController` in order for your app to function at all, you might force cast it using `return vc as! MyViewController`. That way you discover right away that something is off.

Honestly, that's it, as far as I can tell. Just my own approach, but I reserve the `!` for declaring `@IBOutlet`s. Otherwise, 99.999% of the time I unwrap with `if let` or `guard`, or `?` in an an optional chaining situation. There are other ways to know that the value is `nil`. If the optional fails to unwrap, print a message to the console telling you that it failed. To me, a short descriptive message is easier to debug than a crash and an `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value` error. If I want the program to fail, I can still use `fatalError` with a descriptive message:

```
guard let x = someOptional else { fatalError("someOptional is nil in awakeFromNib.") }
```

By reserving `!` for `@IBOutlet`s, every time I get one of those `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value` errors I know exactly where to look to find the source of my problem. I look at my `@IBOutlet` connections in interface builder. Sticking to that policy, and using other tools to identify other values that are `nil` when they shouldn't be, works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives (avoid force unwrapping `!`). Try these out using an non-nil value of `a` as well as when `a` contains `nil`.

```
var a: String? = nil
a = "Hello World"

// Case 1 : nil coalescing operator
print(a ?? "a has value nil, let's not unwrap it!")

// Case 2 : if-let clause
if let a = a {
    print(a)
}
else {
    print("a has value nil, let's not unwrap it!")
}

// Case 3 : guard-let-else clause
func foo(a: String?) {
    guard let a = a else {
        print("a has value nil, let's not unwrap it!")
        return
    }
    print(a)
}
foo(a)
```